# How to efficiently move values from a column to a different column without overwriting values?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to move some dates from one column to the next neighbouring column. I want it to only move cells before a specific date and until it reaches an empty one.

I've tried using the filter method but I don't think it's working for me.

Here's an image of what I'm trying to achieve.

[image: test spreadsheet] 
I selected the cell values that the script should move; the rest should remain where they are. 
 Here's my code:

```
function moveOldEntryDates()
{
  // Get active spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  var oneDayAgo = sheet1.getRange(2, 6, 1, 1);
  Logger.log("First Date: " + oneDayAgo.getValue());

  var sevenDaysAgo = subtractDaysFromDate(oneDayAgo.getValue(), 7);
  Logger.log("Seven days ago Date: " + sevenDaysAgo);

  // Dates start on second row
  var dateOffset = 2;

  // Not working properly
  var FColumn = sheet1.getRange("F6:F").getValues(); // Date Column
  var LastRowInFColumn = FColumn.filter(String).length;
  //var g = e.filter( function(elem, pos){ return (f.indexOf(elem[1]) == pos) })

  Logger.log("Last row in column F is "+ LastRowInFColumn);
  var dateColumn = sheet1.getRange(dateOffset, 6, LastRowInFColumn, 1);

  var dateValues = dateColumn.getValues();
  var currentRow = 0;

   // This while loop finds the start of the outdated dates
  while(dateValues[currentRow][0] != "")
  {
    var dateBuilt = new Date(dateValues[currentRow][0]);
    var less = dateBuilt < sevenDaysAgo;
    Logger.log(dateBuilt + " less than " + sevenDaysAgo + "?: " + less + " at row: " + currentRow + dateOffset);
    // Check if less than 7 days ago
    if(less)
    {
      startOfOutdatedCells = dateValues[currentRow][0]; // if date is less than oneWeekAgo, it's outdated
      // everything after is already outdated.
      break;
    }
    else if(!less)
    {
      currentRow++;
    }    
  }
  var outdatedDateRow = currentRow + dateOffset;
  Logger.log("First outdated date starts in row: " + outdatedDateRow);

  // Create a new range to move
  var outdatedCellRange = sheet1.getRange(outdatedDateRow,6, LastRowInFColumn, 1);
  var outdatedCellRangeValues = outdatedCellRange.getValues();
  var oudatedCellCopy = outdatedCellRange.moveTo(sheet1.getRange(outdatedDateRow, 7)); // currentRow = the current row is at startOfOutdatedCells

}

function subtractDaysFromDate(date, days)
{
  var result = new Date(date.getTime()-days*(24*3600*1000));
  return result
}
```

My guess is that `var LastRowInFColumn = FColumn.filter(String).length;` is not filtering / working properly. Instead of returning an array that only contains String values, it still returns than the entire column, including the empty cells. As a result, this is what happens when I run the script: 
[image: test spreadsheet script] 
You can also notice that it's moving the empty cells and placing them, overwriting the values in the other column. If I run it a third time, it just clears the column because it's moving the empty ones as well.
[image: test spreadsheet script] 
Sorry for the long post! Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You're starting from F2 in your pic1,F6 in  script and F8 in pic2 and 3

Comment: Yes, I made a small mistake with the image, it should not start from F2, rather it should start at F8. Thanks for letting me know, I'll fix that. As for the script I thought "F6" stands for "column F / column number 6". If that's not the case, then maybe that's why my filter method isn't working...

Comment: You're explicitly getting F6:f=> `sheet1.getRange("F6:F").getValues()`. Also, why `F8`?

Comment: Ah, I see. I'll look into that. F8 is the first date that's 7 days less than the first row's date.

Comment: `Filter` won't filter the way you like. Use a plain for-loop, when you encounter the space, break the loop

Answer (score 0):

Since the .filter method was not working the way I wanted, I wrote my own method. Here's the code for anyone who might find this helpful.

```
function getLastRowByColumn()
{
  // Get active spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // <======= Change this
  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = ss.getLastColumn();

  var dates = sheet1.getRange(2,6,lastRow, 1); // <====== Change range values
  var values = dates.getValues();
  var currentRow = 0;
  var rowCounter = 0;
  while(values[currentRow][0] != "")
  {
    rowCounter++;
    currentRow++;
  }
  return rowCounter;
}
```